# Why is this.prop in constructor returning undefined

Tags: javascript, constructor, this, undefined

I'm looking to understand the apparent discrepancy in what the logs of the code below return. I expect them to be equivalent and to not return `undefined`. However, one does return `undefined` while the other does not.

```js
var floors = [ { number : 4, desc : `The obj from the floors array` } ]

function Unit ( number ) {
  this.number = number
  this.floor  = Number( String( this.number )[0] ) // no issue with a this.property reference here
  
  console.log( this.floor ) // evals to 4 here so why not on the next line?
  console.log( floors.find( function ( floor ) { return floor.number === this.floor } ) ) // Why does this return undefined
  console.log( floors.find( function ( floor ) { return floor.number === 4 } ) ) // but this does not?
}

new Unit ( 425 )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because with normal functions, `this` is defined by *how the function is called*, not where the function appears. In your `find` callbacks, `this` isn't the same as it is *outside* your `find` callbacks.

You have at least four options:

1. Pass the second argument to `find`: It defines what `this` will be in the callback:

   ```
   console.log( floors.find( function ( floor ) {
       return floor.number === this.floor;
   }, this ) );
   // ^^^^
   ```
2. Use `Function#bind` to create a *bound* function:

   ```
   console.log( floors.find( function ( floor ) {
       return floor.number === this.floor;
   }.bind( this ) ) );
   // ^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   A *bound* function ignores the `this` that it's called with, instead using the one that's bound to it.
3. Define a variable and set it to `this`, then use that variable within the callbacks:

   ```
   var me = this; // The variable
   console.log( floors.find( function ( floor ) {
       return floor.number === me.floor;
   //                          ^^
   } ) );
   ```
4. Starting with ES2015, you can use an *arrow function*, which closes over the `this` of the context in which it's defined; in your case, you can use the *concise* form without `{}`:

   ```
   console.log( floors.find( floor => floor.number === this.floor ) );
   ```

   Or here's the longer form:

   ```
   console.log( floors.find( floor => { return floor.number === this.floor; } ) );
   ```